# C++ using snprintf in ostream with rvalue buffer, is this well-formed?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, rvalue-reference

I was wondering if I could use `snprintf` formatting in an `ostream` such that I could embed the call to `snprintf` in the stream expression itself. This compiles in GCC 4.9, but is it OK?

```
    cout << [](char (&&buf) [12], int d) { snprintf(buf, 12, "%d", d); return buf; } ({ }, 15) << endl;
```

Comment: That line of code has got to win some award for lambda usage.

Comment: The real question here, IMO, is how `{}` binds to an rvalue of an array type and what it means for this to happen. When we answer that question, the question about whether or not this code has defined behavior will have been answered. Also, you have one extra `)` near the end of that line.

Comment: @cdhowie, I think you are correct, about nature of the question. I removed the extra `)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is well-formed and well-defined. `{}` is used to copy-list-initialize an rvalue reference to `char [12]`, which creates a temporary `char [12]` array to which the reference is bound. This temporary lives until the end of the full expression - in this case, until the semicolon, so a pointer to an element in the array can be safely returned and used for printing within that expression. (The lambda returns a `char *` pointing to the first element of this array.)

Standardese:

§8.5 [dcl.init]/p17:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. [...]
>
> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

§8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]/p3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined
>   as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or
>     direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for
>     the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary. [ *Note*:
>     As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the
>     reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. —*end note*
>     ]

§12.2 [class.temporary]/p5:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2)
>   persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the
>   call.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is OK.  If I understand correctly, the lambda will return an object of type `char[12]` as a temporary (from automatic return type deduction).  That temporary can then be passed into another function, in this case `operator<<()`.

It does potentially mean copies are made, but RVO may take care of that.

UPDATE

As noted in the comments and in the better answer provided by T.C., the return type deduced by this lambda is actually a char* rather than a char[12].  I have confirmed this with code in GCC.

Comment: It doesn't return a `char [12]`. It returns a `char *`.